# DynamoDb changing the value of character being stored

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Requirement: Save a string field with value of "\92" i.e.

```
var request = new PutItemRequest
                {
                    TableName = "USER",
                    Item = new Dictionary<string, AttributeValue>()
                    {
                        {"userid",new AttributeValue { S="USER1"}},
                        {"username",new AttributeValue { S="\\92"}},
                    },
                };
client.PutItem(request);
```

and then when we get the item back the value of username for userid=USER1 we get i.e.

```
Document userDoc = userTable.GetItem("USER1");
string userName = userDoc["username"].AsString();
Console.Writeline(userName);
```

> output Expected: \92 output Actual: 9292

I am guessing it is converting the \ to its unicode value but when we try to retrieve the data back it is not converting it back to \ but leaving it as 92.

Please let me know if this is a bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 4):

Just got an confirmation from AWS folks that it was a bug in their code and the new 1.4.6.3 release of AWS Dot Net SDK should fix it.